# Android: Missing Resource in Intermediates Directory (Is Gradle to Blame?)

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, build.gradle

I'm very new to both Android Studio and OpenCV so please forgive me if this is a poor question.

Having downloaded and installed the OpenCV general libraries as well as the OpenCV SDK for Android, I now want to use Android Studio and the Android NDK to compile one of the sample OpenCV projects for use on my Android phone.

I have followed the instructions on [this page](http://blog.hig.no/gtl/2014/08/28/opencv-and-android-studio/) but am still running into build errors with gradle. The error output statement is as follows:

> .../AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Error:(13, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
>
> Error:(15, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
>
> "Execution failed for
>   task ':app:ProcessDebugResources'"

With my very basic understanding, I'm guessing that this means gradle is reading AndroidManifest.xml within the **build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug** directory, and this manifest is referencing resources that do not exist.

If this was a directory and an xml file that I had created, I'd be looking to replace the missing resources or edit the manifest. But since all files and directories within the build directory are generated by gradle, I don't have a clue what to do.

Why would gradle generate one directory and file (i.e. AndroidManifest.xml), but not another (i.e. the missing resources)?

My best guess at the source of the problem is that something in the **build.gradle** file that the above link provides doesn't match my particular setup. I've tried tweaking **build.gradle** to use different SDK and buildTools versions but that hasn't helped.

I'm running Android Studio 1.0.1 on Mac OSX 10.10.4

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

**Edit:** This is the text from the main AndroidManifest.xml found in the **app/src/main** directory.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.baneofsociety.pleasework">

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>

</manifest>
```

Everything in **app/src/main/res** is copied directly from the OpenCV example files, as per the instructions I was following in the link. I did not find a styles.xml under **app/src/main/res/values**, only strings.xml.

Comment: see first if there is an image named as ic_launcher in drawable and AppTheme in style or not

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` and your `styles.xml` here!

Comment: @AwanishRaj I have added the text from AndroidManifest.xml above. Strangely, I could not find any file labeled styles.xml in any of the project directories.

Comment: Where did you copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` from? Also do you have `ic_launcher.png` in your `/res/drawable-hdpi` folder?

Comment: @Sushrita The only file contained in app/src/main/res/drawable is labeled icon.png

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to refer to resource `ic_launcher` and `AppTheme` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` which in reality don't exist in your project. This usually happens when you blindly copy paste code.

Change your icon in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows, because you have said that you have `icon.png`:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

You also need to add a `styles.xml` file. For this, create a new project in your IDE and copy the auto-generated `styles.xml` file to `res/values/` directory. Usually `styles.xml` contains something like this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Hope it helps! Please read more documentation. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Awanish! Reading more documentation is always on my list of things to do - unfortunately this time I was looking into build.gradle documentation instead of the stuff on manifests.

Comment: @rustyDog No problem. Please accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Awanish Raj's question "Where did you copy the AndroidManifest.xml from?" is what set me on the right track. I was still using the generic AndroidManifest.xml generated by Android Studio, rather than copying across the xml file from the OpenCV sample. Replacing the generic xml with the sample one fixed the problem.